# How to have views exposed filter value show as different value in the url?

Tags: views, search, 9

I have a search page with a Views exposed filter for the name of a taxonomy term. I have added an #autocomplete_route_name to the form element to make this an autocomplete selector for my term names. The autocomplete controller returns this:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  if($term->hasTranslation($langcode)){
    $translated_term = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($term, $langcode);
    $results[] = [
      'value' => $translated_term->getName(),
      'label' => $translated_term->getName(),
    ];
  }
}
return new JsonResponse($results);
```

this works fine, except the url ends up with the term name in the GET (url). Is there any way to have term id here?

I have seen many answers to this question to use hook_views_pre_view. These are fine to modify the value used in the views query, but has no impact on the url variable.

Comment: Can you bit clarify your query like you want to alter the query parameter name 
or specific query parameter value in the URL?

Comment: query is something like term=hybrid+workplace but i want it to be tid=34

Answer (score 0):

**#1:** **To alter Query parameter value in the url of View page**: redirect event subscriber approach used

```
<?php
    
    namespace Drupal\custom_module;
    
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
    use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
    use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
    use Drupal\Core\Url;
    
    /**
     * Execute to changes query parameter value in the url of view page.
     */
    class RedirectSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    
      /**
       * Current Route.
       *
       * @var \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface
       */
      protected $route;
    
      /**
       * The request stack.
       *
       * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
       */
      protected $requestStack;
    
      /**
       * Constructs a RedirectSubscriber object.
       *
       * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $current_route_match
       *   The route match.
       * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $requestStack
       *   The request stack.
       */
      public function __construct(RouteMatchInterface $current_route_match, RequestStack $requestStack) {
        $this->route = $current_route_match;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
      }
    
      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public function redirect(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        $route_name = $this->route->getRouteName();
        // Get category name
        $term_name = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->query->get('category_name');
        // Get term id from category name
        $ary = preg_split('/[()]/', $term_name);
        $tid = $ary[1];
        if ($route_name == 'view.speaker.page_2' && isset($term_name)) {
          if (isset($tid)) {
            // Get all paramters page
            $params = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->query->All();
            // Alter the category_name query parameter value
            if ($params['category_name']) {
              $params['category_name'] = $tid;
            }
            // Set redirect url & pass all parameters to it
            $redirect_url = Url::fromRoute('view.view_bulk_test.page_2')->setOptions(['query' => $params])->toString();
            if ($redirect_url) {
              // Pass Redirect URL.
              $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($redirect_url, 301));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    
      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['Redirect', 20];
        return $events;
      }
    
}
```

**File path:** : module_name/src/RedirectSubscriber.php

**Define: module_name.services.yml** (inside custom module)

```
 services:
  module_name.redirect_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\module_name\RedirectSubscriber
    arguments: ['@current_route_match', '@request_stack']
    tags:
      - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

**In this scenario query parameter whose value altered is autocomplete taxonomy referenced type field & if tid passed then error 'll display:**
There are no taxonomy terms matching "2".

**To fix it:** Used hook hook_views_pre_view():

```
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

function module_name_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, string $display_id, array $args) {
  if (($view->id() == 'speaker')) {
    $exposedInput = $view->getExposedInput();
    // Get term id from category name
    $tid = $exposedInput['category_name'];
    if(isset($tid)){
      // Load term object from term id
      $term = Term::load($tid);
      if(isset($term)){
        // Set value of filter in required format
        $val = $term->label().' '.'('.$tid.')'; 
        $exposedInput['category_name'] = $val;
      }
      // Set the exposed filter value in the view
      $view->setExposedInput($exposedInput); 
    }
  }
}
```

**#2: Query paramter name in the url of view page can be altered by the view  UI.**

Steps:

1. Go to the required view and edit the view
2. Click the filter & filter settings 'll open in the modal
3. You will find 'Filter identifier' field , here you can specify the required parameter name.
   [image]

Comment: Hmm, yes, just redirecting the page to a different url. Seems inefficient but that should work. Thanks. I'll try this out.

Comment: Yeah it's redirecting approach in which redirect to same page with query parameter value altered,

Comment: Tried to work with diff hooks of view before that hook's code execute , the page redirect 
so for now found redirect event subscriber approach helps to achieve functionality.